# Grunt Pageres plugin doesn't display css background url correctly

Tags: npm, gruntjs

Trying Pageres plugin with grunt. Works fine besides background image from css file:

```
.parallax-2 { 
  width:100%;
  background: url(../images/bg-banner-1.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

It displays it zoomed like 1000x. Any ideas how to fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can define the size of your image:

with: **sizes**: ['1200x800', '800x600'],

```
grunt.initConfig({
    pageres: {
        screenshot: {
            options: {
                urls: 'yeoman.io',
                sizes: ['1200x800', '800x600'],
                dest: 'dist'
            }
        },
        multipleUrls: {
            options: {
                urls: ['todomvc.com', 'google.com'],
                sizes: ['800x1000', '400x1000'],
                dest: 'dist',
                crop: true
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I hope that helped you

Comment: That's what I'm saying. In format 1200x800 or 800x600 the css background images are displayed in the screenshot png zoomed 100x.

Comment: try change  sizes: ['10x10', '20x20'], to see what you get, anyway the image gets bigger right? have you checked the size of the images? or that when you open on the html, any online link for me see?